# How to install a mysql server and phpmyadmin on localhost mac

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, webserver

I'm trying to follow [this](https://youtu.be/D6esTdOLXh4) tutorial on how to get started with Python Django but I'm 25 minutes in and all of a sudden the guy pulls up localhost/phpmyadmin and I have no idea how I get that or anything about it on my Mac and I'm just completely lost someone please help thanks.

Comment: There are many youtube videos on how to do it, did you watch them?

Answer (score 0):

1. download & install xampp
2. open Xampp control panel
3. start Apache (webserver) & Mysql (database)
4. open a browser type in localhost/phpmyadmin
5. create a database & the tables you need

you also have to create your project in xampp/htdocs/yourproject and then you can see it in the browser with localhost/yourproject

but i have no clue about python so you will have to figure out that by yourself but that wasnt the question..